# AP Scheduler lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: flask, apscheduler

`APScheduler==3.2.0.post67`
`SQLAlchemy==1.1.1`
`Flask==0.11.1`

The AP Scheduler loses connection to DB

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') [SQL: 'SELECT apscheduler_jobs.id, apscheduler_jobs.job_state \nFROM apscheduler_jobs \nWHERE apscheduler_jobs.next_run_ti     me <= %s ORDER BY apscheduler_jobs.next_run_time'] [parameters: (1626901195.883544,)]`

Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS I think is the reason this is failing, but also not sure why.

When the application starts up is sends a request and looks for available jobs to run. Then when the clock ticks to 0 for the next job to run this error spits out .

`MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`

Thanks

Comment: Same code runs perfectly fine on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The solution was max_allowed_packet size was incorrect.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

Docs if ever needed.